# VisualStateManager inconsistency

Tags: .net, silverlight, visualstatemanager, visualstates

How is that you can declare VisualStates and VisualStateGroups on any object inheriting from FrameworkElement but to call the VisualStateManager.GoToState you need to specify a Control? What's the point of declaring states tan you cannot navigate to them?

This looks like an inconsistency to me. Am I right or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` property is set on the root element of a `ControlTemplate`, which can be a `FrameworkElement` like a `Panel`. However, the `control` parameter of the `GoToState()` method is NOT the root element of the template, it is the `Control` itself, which has the ControlTemplate bound to it.

A bit confusing? Maybe. Not very OOP? Absolutely.